# Access VM Shared Directory from Linux App Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, storage-file-share

we have the new asp.net core web application running on Azure as App Service.
Because of the backward compatibility, we have a bunch of files (from the old version of the application) stored on VM Windows machine running at Azure too. Those files must be there!
And we need to access them from Linux App Service as files and directories as they are.

We wanted to use File Share. But because of the App Service sandbox, it is not possible.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now you have option of mounting or using azure storage with Linux App Service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=portal&pivots=container-linux

You can think of using or moving your filesystem from Azure VM to azure storage and further use Linux App Service mounting to Azure Storage.

The above article contains video with every step on how to do that.

Comment: Great point. Thanks, it works!